# How to enable verbatim environment under self defined environment?

Tags: verbatim, auxiliary-files, write

So I want to define an inline environment `!foo!`, and write `foo` into an exteral file. Here is my source code：

```
\catcode`!=13
\newwrite\mmtlatexfile
\immediate\openout\mmtlatexfile=\jobname.mmtlatex
\newcounter{ExprNum}
\def!#1!{\outputmmtlatex{#1}}
\def\outputmmtlatex#1{%
    \stepcounter{ExprNum}%
    \immediate\write\mmtlatexfile{expression_\roman{ExprNum} = #1}%
}%
```

Clearly I can't write something like `!a % b = c!`, because `%` has special meaning in LaTeX.

Is there any way to ignore these special meaning characters(`& % $ # _ { } ~ ^ \`) inside `!!`?

Comment: Can you show an example of supposed usage?

Comment: @egreg If I write ``some!a % b = c!thing`` in ``foo.tex``, then ``something``should be shown in the generated pdf file, in the meantime, ``a % b = c`` is written in ``foo.mmtlatex``.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to grab the input verbatim. Using a similar approach to `\verb` this might look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\!=\active
\newcounter{ExprNum}
\newwrite\mmtlatexfile
\immediate\openout\mmtlatexfile=\jobname.mmtlatex\relax
\def!{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother
  \dospecials
  \mmttoend
}
\def\mmttoend#1!{%
    \stepcounter{ExprNum}%
    \immediate\write\mmtlatexfile{expression_\roman{ExprNum} = #1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
some!a % b = c!thing
\end{document}
```

The key is *not* to grab the argument until the specials have been deactivated (`\dospecials`). As this is verbatim-like it will not work in the argument of other commands,